# How to remove Picasa originals?

Tags: picasa

I noticed that Picasa (desktop app) take a copy of current photo when you start modifying it. What is the correct procedure to delete these "originals" once I have finished my editing? Should I delete the `.picasaoriginals` folder manually or is there another preferred option?

Comment: This would probably fall outside the scope of what's on topic in superuser. Probably best to ask at the [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange

Comment: @50-3 Picasa is also a software program that can be installed to a PC

Comment: @50-3 I am indeed referring to Picasa Desktop app.

Comment: @Drake Okay I see you also edited the question to correct that. I was only familiar with it as a web app so my mistake

Answer (score 2):

When you have finished editing your photos, click the Save button for the particular folder. This creates a backup of the original photo in `.picasaoriginals`.

You can safely delete the `.picasaoriginals` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal:

```
find . -iname '.picasaoriginals' -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

**If your folder is not synchronized to web** then the manual removal of photos from your computer hard drive is enough, Make Sure that you emptied trash of your computer Drive, if [Sync to web](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/106176) is enabled manually Remove it and delete the original file,it Would Empty the Photos from Computer Drive and original files would be safely removed